# PHP GuzzleHttp . How to send a json post?

Tags: php, symfony, post, guzzle, goutte

I have this post:

```
{"latitude":"","longitude":"","countryCode":"ES","filterPostalCode":"","filterCity":"","filterCountryCode":"ES","searchText":"","nextPageToken":0,"storeType":"normal","checkStoreAvailability":false}
```

And i'm trying to send it like this on Guzzle 6.0+

```
'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Referer' => 'https://www.rituals.com/es-es/stores'],
'body' => '{"latitude":"","longitude":"","countryCode":"ES","filterPostalCode":"","filterCity":"","filterCountryCode":"ES","searchText":"","nextPageToken":0,"storeType":"normal","checkStoreAvailability":false}']
```

But it's not working, any way to send everything without formating it like I posted? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of create Client object

```
$client = new Client([
     'http_errors' => false,
     'verify'      => false,
]);
```

And then your request with params

```
$response = $client->request($requestMethod, $url, array_merge(
    ['json' => $body],
    ['headers' => $headers]
));
```

Comment: Formating it is working but why isn't when I just give the post that website give me? 

[
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
                'Referer' => 'https://www.rituals.com/es-es/stores'],
            'json' => ['{"latitude":"","longitude":"","countryCode":"ES","filterPostalCode":"","filterCity":"","filterCountryCode":"ES","searchText":"","nextPageToken":0,"storeType":"normal","checkStoreAvailability":false}'],
        ]